# Generic Response in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  GenericResponse({
    this.result,
    this.status = 200,
    this.message = "",
  });

  factory GenericResponse.fromJson(final String str) => GenericResponse.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  factory GenericResponse.fromMap(final Map<String, dynamic> json) => GenericResponse(
        status: json["status"],
        message: json["message"],
        result: json["result"],
      );

  final int status;
  final String message;
  final T? result;
}

class GenericListResponse<T> {
  GenericListResponse({
    this.result,
    this.status = 200,
    this.message = "",
  });

  factory GenericListResponse.fromJson(final String str) => GenericListResponse.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  factory GenericListResponse.fromMap(final dynamic json) => GenericListResponse(
        status: json["status"],
        message: json["message"],
        result: json["result"],
      );

  final int status;
  final String message;
  final List<T>? result;
}
```

this is my two classes for response of my requests, all my requests have these response by default and have a result that might be a list or an object. but when I use them I get this error.

```
  Future<void> read({
    required final Function(GenericListResponse<ProductReadDto>) onResponse,
    required final Function(GenericResponse response) onError,
  }) async =>
       httpGet(
        url: "$baseUrl/Product/${type.title}",
        action: (Response response) => onResponse(GenericListResponse<ProductReadDto>.fromMap(response.body)),
        error: (Response response) => onError(GenericResponse.fromMap(response.body)),
      );
```

```
    Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<ProductReadDto>'
```

Answer (score 0):

you are setting `List<ProductReadDto> result = json["result"];` and `json["result"]` will return a list of hash maps, thats why it throws this error.

you should pass the generic from json function to the `fromMap` function too and convert the list `result` from a list of hash maps to a list of the generic type you passed

ex.

```
factory GenericListResponse<T>.fromMap(final dynamic json, T Function(Object? json) fromJsonT) => GenericListResponse(
    status: json["status"],
    message: json["message"],
    result: (json['result'] as List<dynamic>?)?.map(fromJsonT).toList(),
  );
```

and then use it as follows

```
GenericListResponse<ProductReadDto>.fromMap(
    response.body,
    (json) => ProductReadDto.fromJson((json as Map<String, dynamic>?) ?? {}),
);
```